# Is it bad to break out of php inside a function?

Tags: php

More to the point, is one of these faster or considered 'better' than the other?

```
function name_field($name){?>
    <div class="input-wrap">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>"/>
    </div>
<?php }
```

Compared to:

```
function name_field($name){
    $output = '<div class="input-wrap">';
        $output .= '<label for="name">Name:</label>';
        $output .= '<input type="text" id="name" value="' . $name . '"/>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    echo $output;
}
```

Comment: This is more a question of readability than anything else. I'd honestly prefer the second one since, as I said, it's a bit more readable.

Comment: I will be the odd man out and say I prefer the first for echoing `HTML` and the second for returning a compiled variable (`return $output` vs. `echo $output`). Some editors will not HTML color in strings so it's easier to pick out simple HTML errors as they occur in the first example...but hey, either way it works!

Comment: The answer is a matter of opinion. I consider it bad to break out of PHP at all, unless it's a very simple script.

Answer (score 1):

What my preference is ...

use mustache and save this as name_field.html

```
<div class="input-wrap">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" value="{{name}}"/>
</div>
```

and then

```
function name_field($name) {

  echo $this->m->render("name_field", array('name' => $name));
}
```

This completely seperates the HTML from the PHP and for larger examples comes in extremely handy

Comment: +1 For encouraging him not output html from php.